# Wildcard Redirect from subdomains to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, web, subdomain

I tried to redirect all my subdomains and their content to my main domain doing this in htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http:// mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There is a redirect but.. I got redirected to `mydomain.com/index.php` every time... I want to be redirected from `subdomain.mydomain.com/category/article` to `mydomain.com/category/article` but I always got redirected to `mydomain.com/index.php`.

What am I doing wrong? I tried a lot of strings all with the same result. I can only redirect `subdomain.mydomain.com/directory` to `mydomain.com/directory` but when I try to redirect from article to article i got a redirect to `mydomain.com/index.php` and not `mydomain.com/article`.

Hope you can help me guys.

I'm doing this just to prevent the creation of duplicate content because all my subdomains points to the same folder of my main domain and I have the exactly same content on my subdomains and my domain.

Comment: I removed every redirect rule now but it's not working the same :(

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? You rule would actually cause redirect loop.

Comment: The .htaccess is located inside my public_html folder. I also tried to use the cPanel redirect using wildcard as feature but same result. PS: Thanks for the help i really apreciate it

Comment: Here's my actual .htaccess file:        www35. zippyshare .com/v/78094310/file.html

Comment: last redirect is commented (with ## ) because of a redirect loop

Comment: Move all your 301 rules to the top of .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did it but it seems nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. If you look inside my .htaccess file, you will note a

> RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

inside the default joomla htaccess.. i just deleted it and now i can redirect every content i want to http://sbenny.com/blablabla with this 2 lines:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sbenny.com$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sbenny.com/$1 [L,R=301]